# Microsoft.Practices.Composite.Presentation.dll not signed

Tags: prism

More sanity checking than an actual question, so this dll is not signed? Does anyone know if there is any semi-recent version of this that is signed? 
I just find this very strange and i mpretty sure there must be some sort of error on my side
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not signed.  However if you need it signed (like if you wanted to GAC it or something like that), you can do so yourself with the included source code.

This is available here: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, I did that , but I found it very strange they wouldnt sign it no? Its  a pretty basic requirement

Comment: Requirement for what?  There are very few scenarios that actually require you to sign the assemblies and I'm guessing they assumed that for those few people who need that, you have the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Signing an open-source project doesn't make sense. Do you?

- **Include the key file:** In which case anyone can modify the code and sign it as if they're the original author.
- **Don't include the key file:** So now if you need to change the original code you can't sign the modification and you can't reference it without the original signing.

It makes more sense to not sign it and let the person download the code and sign it themselves.

Comment: You can definitely keep the key file out of source but still provide signed versions of your OS library. It has always been considered a best practice to not store the key file with the source to protect it from abuse.

If I provide a binary download of my OS library, then I can sign it with my key and provide the signature so that users can validate it came from me (official). If they want to change it, they can fork the project but would need to use their own key to sign it at that point. This is very common.